# не могу разобраться c настройками slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете нашел, что должна быть одна имплементация slf4j , но  у меня же одна!
Почему выдает ошибку?

Comment: Код нужнов вставлять текстом, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Добавьте зависимости в pom

Comment: Добавил появилось - вывело в кансоль, но вышел новый сток, где написано, что также много импдлементаций

Comment: @LE_1984, не совсем понятно в чем проблема. Надеюсь вы удалили свою зависимость из pom. Эти три достаточны для работы с log4j

Comment: Свою проблему я решил, перекинув проект на community, где также работают и ваши dependency

Answer (score 0):

Проблему я решил переносом проекта в community, буду разбираться с настройками ultimate